# validate username from database table before registration - LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, validation, authentication

I'm trying to validate every user that will register if their username/employee number is existing in the master list.

If it does not exist, an error will be shown. If exists, the registration will enter another validation

Controller:

```
return Validator::make(
            
            [
                'employeenumber'        => 'required|max:9|unique:users|alpha_dash|exists:masterlist',
                'name'                  => 'required',
                'email'                 => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password'              => 'required|min:6|max:30|confirmed',
                'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:password',
            ],
[
                'employeenumber.exists'         => trans('auth.EmployeeNumberNull'),
                'employeenumber.unique'         => trans('auth.EmployeeNumber'),
                'employeenumber.required'       => trans('auth.EmployeeNumberRequired'),
                'name.required'                 => trans('auth.AccNameRequired'),
                'email.required'                => trans('auth.emailRequired'),
                'email.email'                   => trans('auth.emailInvalid'),
                'password.required'             => trans('auth.passwordRequired'),
                'password.min'                  => trans('auth.PasswordMin'),
                'password.max'                  => trans('auth.PasswordMax'),
            ]
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'employeenumber' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `employees` where `employeenumber` = 03-444555) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22):
```

I get server error when registering employee number that is not on database instead of throwing an error.

Comment: you can read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask question in stackoverflow. Please indicate also the error.

Comment: i've edited it. thank you

Comment: `employeenumber` this field don't exist in your database. try double check if there are typos on your database or your query

Comment: Found the error, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, the column should be stated in the validation

`'employeenumber' => 'required|max:9|unique:users|alpha_dash|exists:masterlist',`

should be

`'employeenumber' => 'required|max:9|unique:users|alpha_dash|exists:masterlist,employeenumber',`